# how do i replace the name of multiple objects in a list with names in another list?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I'm currently trying to create a tool, to rename objects in blender, to automatically have lowercase names.
I keep however getting the error: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

My current code is below, can anyone tell me how I can fix this error?

```py
        objs = bpy.context.scene.objects

        #o = old_name l = lowercase
        o = {n.name for n in objs}
        print(o)
        l = [elem.lower() for elem in o]
        count = len(objs)
        i = 0
        print(count)
        while i < count:
            objs[i].name = l()
        i+=1
```

edit: I want to do more with the name than just make it lowercase, but I keep getting stuck on renaming the objects in the right order so that's what I'm trying to fix here

Comment: Hi. `l` is a list. `l()` is trying to call the list as if it were a function, which it is not. What were hoping `l()` would do?

Comment: I want ```l``` to contain the new names of the objects, and assign them as the object name using ```objs[i].name ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your script performs several unnecessary operations when your goal is to rename the objects.

- You're creating a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) of object names by using the `{}` syntax, which isn't necessary since the names are guaranteed to be unique.
- Unless you intend to re-use the old names, it's not necessary to store them.
- You likely don't need to store the new lowercase names either, if you perform your action while iterating over the objects.
- Don't use a `while` loop when you intend to index elements. Use a `for` loop instead, especially if the object is [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#iterators).
- The `l` is a list of strings, therefore using `l()` would result in a `TypeError`, since a list can't be called. It's not a function.

The solution would be to iterate over the objects and rename them one by one.

```
import bpy


for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    obj.name = obj.name.lower()
    # Perform additional tasks with the renamed object here
```

If you have to store the lowercase names in a list:

```
import bpy


names_lowercase = []

for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    name = obj.name.lower()
    obj.name = name
    names_lowercase.append(name)
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me out